# setting up mongodb 3 node cluster with replSet()

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a 3 node cluster with mongodb. I am trying to connect this 3 nodes and send some transaction, but I am getting the following error.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Asset.py", line 37, in 
sent_creation_tx = bdb.transactions.send(fulfilled_creation_tx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bigchaindb_driver/driver.py", line 319, in send
method='POST', path=self.path, json=transaction, headers=headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bigchaindb_driver/transport.py", line 58, in forward_request
headers=headers,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bigchaindb_driver/connection.py", line 57, in request
raise exc_cls(response.status_code, text, json)
bigchaindb_driver.exceptions.TransportError: (407, '\n\n<TITLE>ERROR: Cache Access Denied</TITLE>\n<STYLE type="text/css"></STYLE>\n\n\n
```

This is the rs.initiate()

```
> bigchain-rs:PRIMARY> rs.initiate()
{
"info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
"me" : "lakshman:27017",
"info" : "try querying local.system.replset to see current configuration",
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "already initialized",
"code" : 23,
"codeName" : "AlreadyInitialized"
}
```

And rs.status()

```
> rs.status
bigchain-rs:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
"set" : "bigchain-rs",
"date" : ISODate("2017-08-29T09:26:35.207Z"),
"myState" : 1,
"term" : NumberLong(13),
"heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
"optimes" : {
"lastCommittedOpTime" : {
"ts" : Timestamp(1503998790, 1),
"t" : NumberLong(13)
},
"appliedOpTime" : {
"ts" : Timestamp(1503998790, 1),
"t" : NumberLong(13)
},
"durableOpTime" : {
"ts" : Timestamp(1503998790, 1),
"t" : NumberLong(13)
}
},
"members" : [
{
"_id" : 0,
"name" : "localhost:27017",
"health" : 1,
"state" : 1,
"stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
"uptime" : 298,
"optime" : {
"ts" : Timestamp(1503998790, 1),
"t" : NumberLong(13)
},
"optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-08-29T09:26:30Z"),
"electionTime" : Timestamp(1503998498, 1),
"electionDate" : ISODate("2017-08-29T09:21:38Z"),
"configVersion" : 1,
"self" : true
}
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

I am not able to see any nodes getting added when i check using rs.status.

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: thnks 4  the comment